# If $I=t\int_{0}^{s/t}f(s+tx)$ then I depends on what variable

Tags: calculus

This is a practice question for the GRE. The answer is that it depends on s solely.
However, when I was working through the integrals I noticed that if
$0=x_{1}\leq ... \leq x_{n}=1$ is a partition of $[0,1]$, then $0=\frac{x_{1}}{l}\leq ... \leq \frac{x_{n}}{l}=1/l$ is a partition of $[0,1/l]$. From this it seems to follow that
$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx=l\int_{0}^{1/l}f(lx)dx$. My reasoning for this is that
$$
\sum_{i=2}^{n}\frac{1}{l}f(\frac{x_{i}}{l}l)(x_{i}-x_{i-1})
$$
would be the (right) Reimann sum of the continuous function $f(lx)$ which is
$1/l$ the (right) Reimann of $f(x)$.
This to me would imply that $t\int_{0}^{s/t}f(t(s/t+x))dx=\int_{0}^{s}f(s/t+x)dx$ or in otherwords the function would rely on both s and t. This does not appear to be the case however and I am wondering why?

Comment: Use the change of variables $u=s+tx$. Then $du=tdx$ (you didn't write the integral was over x but I am assuming that is the case). The $t$ will be absorbed in du and the new bounds (obtained by substituting $x=0$ and $x=s/t$ into $u=s+tx$) will not depend on t.

Comment: That is much simpler than what I was trying to do haha. Thanks!